# New to javascript & jquery. Am I not closing something correctly? Dreamweaver only says "Syntax Error"

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Code to bring each link on to screen and in position
        $("#link1").animate({
            left: '30px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1000);
        $("#link2").animate({
            left: '80px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1400);
        $("#link3").animate({
            left: '130px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1400);
        $("#link4").animate({
            left: '180px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1600);
        $("#link5").animate({
            left: '230px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1800);

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link1").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link2").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link3").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link4").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link5").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link1").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link1").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link2").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link2").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link3").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link3").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link4").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link4").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link5").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link5").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });



        // Parallax Scroll
        $(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {
            parallaxScroll();
        });

        function parallaxScroll() {
                var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('#bblogo1').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo2').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.5)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo3').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.3)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo4').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.9)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo5').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo6').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.1)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo7').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.4)) + 'px');

                $('#bbspinner').animate(function (){
                    $(this).css
("background","url(images/bblogorender0000.png)");
                });

         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this one you are missing closing brackets

```
       $(document).ready(function () 
        // Code to bring each link on to screen and in position
                      {  $("#link1").animate({
            left: '30px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1000);
        $("#link2").animate({
            left: '80px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1400);
        $("#link3").animate({
            left: '130px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1400);
        $("#link4").animate({
            left: '180px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1600);
        $("#link5").animate({
            left: '230px',
            top: '5px'
        }, 1800);

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link1").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link2").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link3").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link4").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Fade in & out on hover
        $("#link5").hover(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(150);
            $(this).fadeIn(150);
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link1").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link1").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link2").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link2").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link3").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link3").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link4").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link4").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });

        // Nudge the link when "clicked"
        $("#link5").mousedown(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "5px");
        });

        $("#link5").mouseup(function () {
            $(this).css("padding-top", "0px");
        });



        // Parallax Scroll
        $(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {
            parallaxScroll();
        });

        function parallaxScroll() {
                var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('#bblogo1').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo2').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.5)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo3').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.3)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo4').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.9)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo5').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo6').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.1)) + 'px');
                $('#bblogo7').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.4)) + 'px');

                $('#bbspinner').animate(function (){
                    $(this).css
("background","url(images/bblogorender0000.png)");
                });
        }
                      });
```

**You can check for Javascript validation here http://jsfiddle.net/**

Comment: Thank you, the missing } to close the parallax scroll resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

RIght at the end, at the bottom of `parallaxScroll`, you need to put a `}` before the `});` you have there. The `});` closes the document `ready` call you start at the very beginning, so you need it, but you need to close the `parallaxScroll` function first:

```
    function parallaxScroll() {
            var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('#bblogo1').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo2').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.5)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo3').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.3)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo4').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.9)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo5').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.6)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo6').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.1)) + 'px');
            $('#bblogo7').css('top', '-' + ((scrolledY * 0.4)) + 'px');

            $('#bbspinner').animate(function (){
                $(this).css("background","url(images/bblogorender0000.png)");
            });
    } // <==== Here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer above from ohgodwhy, you are not closing your document.ready either.  Where you current last line is:

So you need to close your parallax scroll as above, but you also need to close your document.ready with a

```
});
```

prior to declaring that function.

Answer (score 2):

you can end the document ready with }); but it will validate automatically in some browser,

I suggest to test your application on **IE** so you will know the syntax errors.